# RxJava - Catching Consumer Exception

Tags: android, lambda, rx-java, rx-android

I'm currently trying to find a better solution to my network handling within my Android application. Currently, I'm using RxJava, and a few `Consumer` classes.

Consumer

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    /**
     * Consume the given value.
     * @param t the value
     * @throws Exception on error
     */
    void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

NetworkConsumer

```
abstract class NetworkConsumer<T> : Consumer<NetworkResponse<T>> {

    override fun accept(response: NetworkResponse<T>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            onSuccess(response.data)
        } else {
            onFailure()
        }
    }

    // other functions such as onSuccess and onFailure
}
```

Using the NetworkConsumer

```
UserService.login(email, password)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(object : NetworkConsumer<LoginResponse>() {
                        override fun onSuccess(response: LoginResponse) {
                            super.onSuccess(response)
                            startMainActivity()
                        }

                        override fun onFailure() {
                            Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Could not login.", Toast.SHORT_LENGTH).show()
                        }

                    })
```

Now, this works well in most normal cases, such as a successful login, or a 404 error. However, if there is an `Exception`, such as a `HttpException` or a `SocketTimeOutException`, the `onFailure()` will not be called.

The only solution I found for this problem was to use another `Consumer` that handles `Exceptions` in the RxJavaPlugins.

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(new NetworkErrorConsumer());
```

NetworkErrorConsumer

```
class NetworkErrorConsumer : Consumer<Throwable> {
    override fun accept(exception: Throwable) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that to notify the UI that there is an error, I would need to use an event bus to send a message back to the Activity.

Is there a better solution that would let me `catch` those `Exceptions` within my `NetworkConsumer`?

I would really like a solution that would allow me to use the Lambda style when calling `login`, instead of creating another Object.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you're not passing this `NetworkErrorConsumer` as a second parameter for the `subscribe()` method? this should catch any exception occurs. And you can pass it as Lamda expression

Comment: That's a good idea about the `NetworkErrorConsumer`, but I don't want to have to pass it into every network call. Any way to route all network errors into the same spot? Also, I could not do a Lambda expression, I can only do it with the `object: NetworkErrorConsumer` syntax. I'm trying to write an extension function for this, but I cannot get the correct syntax.

Comment: Check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a version of the `subscribe()` method that accepts an `Observer`, you can create a base one with base exception handling:

```
abstract class NetworkObserver<T> : Observer<NetworkResponse<T>> {

    override fun onError(exception: Throwable) {
        //your base exception handling
    }

    override fun onNext(response: NetworkResponse<T>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            onSuccess(response.data)
        } else {
            onFailure()
        }
    }

    override fun onComplete() {}

    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

    //onSucess & onFailure functions

}
```

Then use an implementation of this class for your login logic:

```
UserService.login(email, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : NetworkObserver<LoginResponse>() {
                    override fun onNext(response: LoginResponse) {
                        super.onNext(response)
                        //additional logic
                    }

                    override fun onSuccess(response: LoginResponse) {
                        super.onSuccess(response)
                        startMainActivity()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure() {
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Could not login.", Toast.SHORT_LENGTH).show()
                    }

                    //you can override onError() method if
                    //you need additional exception handling logic
                })
```

But with this approach you won't be able to use Lamda style

Comment: Hi y.allam, that solution seems like a good start. I'm testing with airplane mode, and it correctly throws an error when trying to make the call the first time. However, the second time I make the call, it doesn't get caught in the onError. Could this be an issue with not unsubscribing?

Comment: I don't think so, how did you implement it?

Comment: I implemented it as exactly as you did, it works as expected. But for some reason, when the second calls fails, it doesn't call onFailure. It calls `onSubscribe`, but not `onFailure` or `onComplete`. For example, I have a button to login. In airplane mode, clicking will show a `ProgressDialog`, then it'll fail immediately as expected. But then clicking the button again will not fail, it'll just subscribe and sit there with the `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: This was the correct answer, the issue was somewhere else in my code. Thank you.